# Getting the full camera view

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

When your taking a photo with a camera, your not getting all the camera view right?

I mean in a portrait photo take

[image]

I will have much more hight then a landscape photo:

[image]

Where ill have much more width, right?
But the camera is a circle so that means the the image can be actuality taken with a larger area, I mean the hight and the width together!
The camera is probably getting the hole image, but cropping it according to the screen, landscape or portrait.

If i would like to get the full image that the camera is getting, how can i achieve that?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks!

**Edit**

After a long search that came out with nothing so far, even if someone knows about a way to display a landscape camera, in a portrait mode, that would help to.
What i mean is display a view were there is more to see on the left and right sids, hope i'm clear enough with my question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the sensor has roughly the same proportions as the screen. Its aspect ration is around 1.33 (4/3) or maybe 1.5 (3/2), depends on the phone model. the only round thing in the camera is the lens that projects a circle of light around the sensor. When you rotate your phone the sensor is naturally rotated as well so you always get the full output in every shot.

Comment: Don't you think that by maybe getting the Raw image from the camera, i could make a larger Image then what apple provides? if the lens are  circle doesn't that mean that you could get a wider image the 4/3?

Comment: Raw image only means unprocessed data, but the sensor's shape isn't a square but a rectangle. What you see is what you get. Honestly :)